# Python - install Pillow and MySQL-python on 1and1 hosting

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-imaging-library

I've created python virtual environment, installed django using pip and now I would like to install Pillow and MySQL-python using pip but it fails during compile process.
(starting with python.h no such file or directory)

Has anyone tried intall some of these on 1and1 hosting ?
Maybe compile it on different machine or other solution ?

Comment: Focus you question on just one of these packages and show the error message from the failed compile process.  Without these details your question is unlikely to be answered.

Answer (score 0):

There's not really enough detail here to help. But one possibility is that you don't have the development package for python installed. If you are using Debian or Ubuntu, you can do `sudo apt-get install python-dev` to install it.